# Send messages to a safari window in the dashboard with applescript

Tags: safari, applescript, dashboard

I'm trying to send messages via applescript to a safari window in the dashboard. Sending messages to normal safari is simple enough, but no clue how to do it in the dashboard. Is this possible?

Comment: The dashboard isn't scriptable and I don't see any safari commands for the dashboard... so I'd say it's not possible.

Comment: do you mean in a dashboard widget?